# What does the surname suffix IN mean?

Tags: sens, suffixes, noms-de-famille

Many French surnames end with the letters I N   (Blouin, Potvin, Morin, Jolin).  What does that mean?

Comment: Why would surnames mean anything?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Surnames are not what the question is about; endings are what it all about; endings  might means something and they sometimes do  in English, for instance: Smithson, Johnson, … Il y a des noms comme cela en français: Gagnerault, Langlade, Patureau ; ces trois-là semblent avoir été formés à partir de « Gagner », « Langlais », « Pâture ».

Comment: @TeleportingGoat All surnames used to mean "something".

Comment: @LPH Gagnerault vient de **gagnier** (laboureur), Langlade vient d' **anglade** (parcelle de terrain formant un **angle**), Patureau vient probablement de **pâture** mais peut-être directement de **pâtre** (berger).

Comment: Thank you, yes, I'm curious about any clue that we might glean from the surname to a family's possible origins in France..among other reasons.   Prefixes/suffixes are interesting  ways to distinguish one person or family from another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In** can be a suffix but when a surname ends with the letters **in** it is nowadays rarely (never ?) understood as a suffix, even if centuries ago it would have meant something.

The suffix **in** added to a noun means "of or pertaining to, of the nature of", it shows the relationship to whatever that words represents. The same as the English suffix *ine*.

A *citadin* is someone from the city (*cité*).
An *angevin* is someone who lives in the town of Angers (or the Anjou area).
*Chevalin* is an adjective to show the relationship to horses (*cheval* in French).
*Serpentine* is a spotted stone that looks like the skin of a snake (*serpent* in French).
An *Augustin* is a monk belonging to the order of Saint Augustine.

Giving people surnames started in the Middle Ages in France (and in a lot of European countries I think, the custom is a lot older in China I've been told).  The surname was given according to the person's location or job. But nowadays, even when people know that, they have forgotten the origin of their surname, or just do not think about it, it has no significance to them whatsoever.

You say "many French surnames end with the letters IN", I wonder where you got that idea, "many" would not be the word I would use. Among your examples, Blouin, Potvin, and Jolin are fairly rare, only Morin is relatively frequent.
The most popular French surname: *Martin* does end with IN though. It was a first name before it was also used as a surname.

I would surmise that someone with the surname *Potvin* had ancestors that originated from Poitou (a *Poitevin* nowadays is someone who lives in Poitou).

*Jolin* might be related to *jol* (a Nordic winter solstice celebration, it's called "yule" in modern English and unknown in France).

*Morin* could have been given to someone coming from a place called *Maury* (there are several places with that name).

I had no idea about *Blouin* but I found it on [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blouin). It is of Germanic origin, it means "soft" (bili-) "friend" (-win). I do not know of a place called *Blouin* in France, but there seems to be one in Quebec.

---

Edit : I have found confirmation about *Jolin* [here](https://www.filae.com/nom-de-famille/JOLIN.html). And as you see it is a quite a rare name.

Comment: Thanks.  We visit Quebec & Ile d'Orleans frequently and have noticed a high frequency of names ending in IN so I was curious if it meant anything special ...maybe a diminutive perhaps. (Poulin, Drouin, Pellerin, Gosselin, Aubin, Paquin, Asselin, Lemelin, Chauvin, Fortin, Toupin, Turpin),  along with the ones I mentioned before - and others....

Comment: I can confirm we have a lot of surnames ending in -in. But I'm not prepared to speculate if it has a meaning or even a generalized rule. Pellerin for example literally means something along the lines of "traveler", whereas Drouin is a diminutive of Drouet, which itself comes from the old French "droue", meaning "German warrior". We have a lot of diminutives in surnames here. Jolette -> Jolet -> Jolin. Gaudette -> Gaudet -> Gaudreau, etc...

Comment: As for Morin, it's derived from a prejorative old French word, "more" or "maure", describing brown skinned Muslim men who conquered the Iberian Peninsula in the 18th century.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey About Morin  the *maure* origin is only one of the theories given by  specialists. The place/job origin of surnames is a very strong theory prevailing in lots of countries. About Drouet our different sources agree, I never said *in* always depicted the origin, I just said it usually did. Just as *ette* is almost always a diminutive.

Comment: Thank you...very interesting.  Regarding Jolin (my patrilineal line), I've seen documents where they sign alternately Jolin, Jollin, Jollain. My early research showed Jolins in Oulins, France (Eure-et-Loire)  so I wondered if Jolin was a possible perversion of that place name - as in Je viens d'Oulins,  degraded to J'oulins, Jolin

Comment: @Shirley *Jolin* (or Jollin or Jollain, all pronounced the same way) might very well come from Oulins. We can read on the website of the [village of Oullins](http://www.oulins.fr/le-village/histoire/) that the original name was *OLINS* (probably because olive trees used to grow there. Just checked the telephone directory and there's a *Jaulin* (would be pronounced the same as Jolin) family living there.